# RabbitMQ C#: How to get dead letter queue header properties (and decode them)

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

When I want to decode the `x-first-dead-queue` property of the dead letter, I get the following error:

`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'byte[]'`

This is the code that runs when a new dead letter arrives:

```
consumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

                var originalQueueHeader = ea.BasicProperties.Headers["x-first-death-queue"];
                var originalQueue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(originalQueueHeader);
            };
```

Message resolves well, but the originalQueue throws the  `cannot convert from 'object' to 'byte[]'` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to decode the messages, you need to cast the `object{byte[]}` to a `byte[]`.

So for example, if you want to get the `x-first-dead-queue`, you need to do the following:

```
var originalQueueHeader = (byte[])ea.BasicProperties.Headers["x-first-death-queue"];
```

This way the `object{byte[]}` will be casted to a `byte[]`.

To get the string as readable text, do the following:

```
var originalQueue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(originalQueueHeader);
```

This can be done for any of the headers. If you want to do this on, for example a numeric header (`x-delivery-count`), it's as simple as:

```
var deliveryCount = (long)ea.BasicProperties.Headers["x-delivery-count"];
```

And it returns the deliveryCount